# Container takes entire width even though the width is set to 50

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm observing a very strange behavior. I have set the `width` of the `Container` to `50` even then it's taking the entire `width` of the screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppDrawerNew extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 50,
      color: Colors.green,
    );
  }
}
```

I tried wrapping the `Container` inside a `SizedBox` as well. Even then it occupies the entire `width` of the screen.

```
class AppDrawerNew extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 50.0,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. What can I try next?

Comment: Try to width double.infinity

Comment: can you share where you are using `AppDrawerNew `, i think wrap with `Row` and give `Container width`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AppDrawerNew());
}
class AppDrawerNew extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            width: 50.0,
            height: 100.0,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the container must be a child of MaterialApp and Scaffold

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 50, maxWidth: 50),
      color: Colors.green,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Study about **constraints** concept, it is more important!

In documentation is the best for this:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints